# Bootstrap BlueImp file upload Java Controller Resolved

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-file-upload, java-6, blueimp

I have added [BlueImp Jquery multiple fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to my project. 
The server side of the download uses PHP, but I want to use a Java Controller.

I've changed Blueimp's main.js to send the files to my controller - 'saveImages'. This part works and now it is sent to my Java controller.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'saveImages'
    });
```

When selecting/uploading an image,
The headers show:

```
Connection  close
Content-Length  5717
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 26 Mar 2014 19:43:42 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  94000
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------
```

The Post Information shows:

```
-----------------------------1873186311532063957277019191 
Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="files[]"; 
filename="1.jpg" 
Content-Type: image/jpeg 
ÿØÿà�JFIF��`�`��ÿá�Exif��II*����������ÿÛ�C�ÿÛ�CÿÀ���"�ÿÄ����������������� ÿÄ�����������������ÿÄ�����������������ÿÄ�����������������ÿÚ���?�¿ÿÙ 
-----------------------------1873186311532063957277019191--
```

This is the response from a PHP server - but I need to know how to do it with Java

```
{"files":[{"url":"http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv97t6a-7QLgNXnhcK10mnbBojaAwHAL2oei6ySkhR_DKk6k5kDrS_tVhlAxFnCkYncEBM3IyeZ6n_oKXItO9dhoxcizw15pPtlA3-i53vc02Oh62RSqEdbK4QLvPwsFGdBOBmCjoNu8TOfl6m0eu1-Tquspryi48UOPXNe4eRfyrEJmBlJM/1.jpg",
"thumbnailUrl":"http://lh4.ggpht.com/b5ABUz-uqTUynXXNvHSlYcAj3nRnlYVIEAhcSZKWXHcwI_jaDZCaNDuNK-gPjeiIMy9nUIAiwS5l1o3IttA5MikPJOEXkQjFCg=s80",
"name":"1.jpg",
"type":"image/jpeg",
"size":309,
"deleteUrl":"http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv97t6a-7QLgNXnhcK10mnbBojaAwHAL2oei6ySkhR_DKk6k5kDrS_tVhlAxFnCkYncEBM3IyeZ6n_oKXItO9dhoxcizw15pPtlA3-i53vc02Oh62RSqEdbK4QLvPwsFGdBOBmCjoNu8TOfl6m0eu1-Tquspryi48UOPXNe4eRfyrEJmBlJM/1.jpg?delete=true",
"deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

JSON

```
POST http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/

200 OK
    2.06s   
POST http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/

200 OK
    1.18s   
HeadersPostResponseJSON
Sort by key


files
[Object { url="http://jquery-file-uplo...PXNe4eRfyrEJmBlJM/1.jpg",    thumbnailUrl="http://lh4.ggpht.com/b5...IttA5MikPJOEXkQjFCg=s80", name="1.jpg", more...}]

0
Object { url="http://jquery-file-uplo...PXNe4eRfyrEJmBlJM/1.jpg", thumbnailUrl="http://lh4.ggpht.com/b5...IttA5MikPJOEXkQjFCg=s80", name="1.jpg", more...}

url
"http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv97t6a-7QLgNXnhcK10mnbBojaAwHAL2oei6ySkhR_DKk6k5kDrS_tVhlAxFnCkYncEBM3IyeZ6n_oKXItO9dhoxcizw15pPtlA3-i53vc02Oh62RSqEdbK4QLvPwsFGdBOBmCjoNu8TOfl6m0eu1-Tquspryi48UOPXNe4eRfyrEJmBlJM/1.jpg"

thumbnailUrl
"http://lh4.ggpht.com/b5ABUz-uqTUynXXNvHSlYcAj3nRnlYVIEAhcSZKWXHcwI_jaDZCaNDuNK-gPjeiIMy9nUIAiwS5l1o3IttA5MikPJOEXkQjFCg=s80"

name
"1.jpg"

type
"image/jpeg"

size
309

deleteUrl
"http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv97t6a-7QLgNXnhcK10mnbBojaAwHAL2oei6ySkhR_DKk6k5kDrS_tVhlAxFnCkYncEBM3IyeZ6n_oKXItO9dhoxcizw15pPtlA3-i53vc02Oh62RSqEdbK4QLvPwsFGdBOBmCjoNu8TOfl6m0eu1-Tquspryi48UOPXNe4eRfyrEJmBlJM/1.jpg?delete=true"

deleteType
"DELETE"
```

## RESOLVED

```
@RequestMapping(value = "saveImages", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String saveImages(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestPart("files") MultipartFile files, @RequestBody String x)
        throws Exception {

    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(files.getBytes());
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

........
```

## I resolved this myself and have updated the Controller to reflect it. I hope it helps others. If my answer isn't the most efficient, I would appreciate any comments. Thanks.

My environment:

- Java 1.6
- Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE,
- Twitter Bootstrap v3.1.1
- Maven 2.4.1

Comment: I have managed to get this working and have updated the post to reflect the changes to the controller. If there is a more efficient way to achieve this, I would appreciate knowing about it. Thanks.